# Android - как отловить нажатие клавиши на Bluetooth-клавиатуре?

Tags: android, клавиатура, java, bluetooth

Здравствуйте! В своём приложении я пытаюсь сделать поддержку внешних клавиатур. Пока что пользователю будут доступны для нажатия только клавиши

`U (код 49)`

`H (код 36)`

`J (код 38)`

`K (код 39)`

Вопрос: как отловить нажатия этих клавиш; как сделать так, чтобы на экране держалась надпись "Кнопка + (код)", пока юзер зажимает клавишу? На плюсы не скуплюсь.

Comment: Пока что нашёл единственное решение: использовать KeyEvent. Есть ли ещё варианты?

Comment: А других вариантов в Андроиде, кажется, и нет.

Comment: В это статье дочдчиво объяснено http://m.geektimes.ru/post/140384/